# Fourier vs Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

In Fourier transform we shift from **time domain to frequency domain** through a general formula but intuition behind this formula lies in translating the signal to another plane and then aiming for center of mass and the formula of average came from there[image]

[image]

Reference https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY
(An amazing video by 3b1b explaining fourier transform)

In Laplace transform we shift from **time domain to complex s domain** of course a formula exist but i want to know how this formula comes up . In other words, what was in mind of Laplace when he was somehow deriving this formula [image]

How come integrating in time domain equal to dividing by s and derivating means multiplication by s . Similarly  **exponentiating in time domain is equal shifting in s domain .**
[image]

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Steve Brunton has an excellent video explaining the Laplace transform as a generalized Fourier transform:   https://youtu.be/7UvtU75NXTg

Comment: @copper.hat i have edited a bit i hope its better now